# Where to put reusable pure functions in java?

Tags: spring, java-8

I can't decide where to store reusable pure functions in Java. Example :

```
class ServiceA(){

   private C pureFunction1(A a, B b) {
     //code to produce C c;
     return c;      
   }
}


class ServiceB(){
   private C pureFunction1(A a, B b) {
     //code to produce C c;
     return c;      
   }
}
```

According to DRY i should extract this pure function somewhere.

I've considered to put it into following places :

- Static helper class (smell + against SOLID's dependency inversion principle)
- Spring bean (isn't it an overkill for just a pure function)
- Super class (does not feel like a right thing for two independent services)
- Interface with default method (Interfaces have different purpose)

Where would you recommend to put code for pureFunction1?

Comment: How does moving the method `pureFunction1` to a class dedicated to provide the `pureFunction1` functionality violate the SOLID principle?

Comment: @Holger In general case: call to static method could hide external dependencies and cause side effects. If static method has side effect then it definitely violates dependency inversion principle. 
In case of pure function I don't think it does, therefore I asked the community.

Comment: Any method could have side effects, whether `static` or not. And any method could hide dependencies. It’s the responsibility of the methods, not to have these issues. That shouldn’t stop us from using methods.

Comment: Calling a function pure is redundant. You're either talking about a language construct (e.g. a method) which may be pure or not or a function, which is pure by definition.

Comment: I agree with the points @Holger made. I'd try to avoid having utility or helper classes though (unless you're writing a library). Those kinds of generic names indicate you are violating separation of concerns. You should think about your domain(s) and where their boundaries are.

Comment: @ReaSand of course, the class hosting `pureFunction1` should have a name reflecting the responsibility to provide `pureFunction1`, but without additional context, we can’t suggest a good name. The term “helper class” only reflects the absence of a good name. In the end, all classes are supposed to be helpful.

Comment: @Holger yeah I see that point :) I was drawing my conclusions (probably prematurely given the abstract nature of the question) from the fact that the signatures of both of the methods are equal and yet inhabit different services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- My preference would be for static helper class if there is no business logic involved in the method. For example, computing dates which don't have any business logic would be a right candidate for static helper class.
- Spring bean can be an option if there is some proper business logic involved in the method
- Having superclass may not be the right idea. Reasons [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277358/implementing-common-logic-in-base-class)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer static helper class. With java 8 you can declare static method in interface (and implement it in your services).

No difference between spring bean and static helper class for your case
Super class - not good idea without multiple inheritance feature.

Comment: “With java 8 you can declare static method in interface (and implement it in your services)”—which you should not do. If the type containing the helper methods has no semantics, there is no “is a” relationship that justifies an inheritance. Besides that, the Java 8 designers were clever enough to make this anti-pattern pointless, as `static` methods of interfaces are not inherited. You gain nothing with that. If you want to save typing, using `import static`.